# How do I unlock the hidden characters?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

There are at least two hidden characters on the selection screen for Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3.  How do I unlock them?

This is the PS-Vita version if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have Jill Valentine or Shuma-Gorath? I know they were available for the original Marvel Vs Capcom 3 as DLC, and they are definitely still downloadable in the Ultimate Version. You'd have to drop some cash in order to get them though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel_vs._Capcom_3#Playable_characters

**Edit:**

Also:
[image: Fully unlocked character select screen]

Note Jill Valentine in the upper left and Shuma-Gorath in the upper right.

Comment: A. Still's answer above is pretty much right on the money, but I will confirm that they are indeed available on the Ultimate edition for a small sum of cash, of course. In my opinion, Jill Valentine is actually a very useful character (along with Wesker... kick ass :P) once you grow used to her controls. I have not tried Shuma-Gorath as of yet, but I might the next time I head over to my friend's place. Go ahead and accept A. Still's answer, would ya? :P

Comment: @linkus2323 I'm not interested in DLC characters, but ones that come with the base game that are hidden as unlockables.  Galactus is one of them, I want to know whats the other one

Comment: @yx Added an image showing what appears to be a fully unlocked character select screen

Comment: thanks for the screenshot, that helps a lot.  I'll award the bounty once it lets me (in a day)

Comment: Sure. I'd have added it from the beginning if I'd thought to look for it.

Comment: Note that these dlc characters are no longer available. If you don't have them yet, it's not happening. http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2013/dec/18/combofiend-last-chance-tournament-organizers-grab-shuma-gorath-and-jill-ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3/

Answer (score 1):

The only unlockable character I can find any details for is "Galactus" (from Marvel's universe). You unlock him by earning 30,000 Player Points (or XP) and pressing:

- L1 + SELECT + X (for PS3/Vita) or
- LB + BACK + A (for X-Box)

on the character select screen.

The other unlockables I think must be those from Marvel vs Capcom 3 vanilla (the version I have). These are:

- Akuma - Get 2000 PP
- Hsien-Ko - 6000 PP
- Sentinel- 4000 PP
- Taskmaster - 8000 PP

Comment: I'm playing on the Vita, and I see two locked character slots on the character selection menu, one in the top right and one in the top left, so one for each side.  However, I already have Akuma, Sentinel, etc.  Not sure if I have Hsien-Ko I should go check later.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of January 2014, Jill and Shuma Gorath are no longer available. The dlc was taken down from the shop, and they are no longer available to purchase for anybody who has not yet bought them. It is speculated that this is due to CAPCOM's rights to the Marvel characters expiring.

http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2013/dec/18/combofiend-last-chance-tournament-organizers-grab-shuma-gorath-and-jill-ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3/